# Node.js HTTP won't make connection with Unix Socket on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, raspberry-pi, unix-socket

So I have my Raspberry Pi currently running a unix socket with the  library and if I make a simple get request in my browser like `10.0.0.200:2500` I get the response message I want (just a string of text). I also get the same result using PostMan so I KNOW the socket is working find.

The issue is when I am using Node.js to make this same request with

```
var options = {
  host: '10.0.0.200',
  port: 2500,
  path: '/'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

I keep getting a `{ [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 0, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT' }` message in node

My socket is also showing

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.200:2500
Connection: close
```

So Idk why the conneciton is closed and I even tried sending a header with `connection : keep-alive` and that didn't help either

Comment: If you're specifying a `host` and `port`, you're *not* connecting over a *unix socket*, you're connecting over *TCP*.

Comment: Does the server app running on port 2500 return a proper HTTP response? If not, you don't want to use `http`, but [`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

Comment: What is serving the responses? Is the source code available? Have you ran tcpdump to verify that the server is responding with a well-formed HTTP response?

Comment: @robertklep How would I used .net since I need to specify the IP, I am trying to connect from node on a different machine like I was with the other Get request

Comment: @FrickeFresh [`net.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectlistener).

Comment: @robertklep lol, lack of seeing options in doc.. Thanks, closing question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @roberklep

I got it work using `net.connect()` and passing the options argument found here [net.connect()](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener)

also another good source for example of use [here](https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757)

Comment: I had the same issue with another service. This helped me get `net.connect()` working. I also needed to write the correct HTTP request in the connect callback, following this example: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8514#issuecomment-58556129